# How can I optimise requests/second under peak load for Django, UWSGI and Kubernetes

Tags: django, kubernetes, uwsgi, scaling

We have an application that experiences some pretty short, sharp spikes - generally about 15-20mins long with a peak of 150-250 requests/second, but roughly an average of 50-100 requests/second over that time. p50 response times around 70ms (whereas p90 is around 450ms)

The application is generally just serving models from a database/memcached cluster, but also sometimes makes requests to 3rd party APIs etc (tracking/Stripe etc).

This is a Django application running with uwsgi, running on Kubernetes.

I'll spare you the full uwsgi/kube settings, but the TLDR:

```
# uwsgi
master = true
listen = 128 # Limited by Kubernetes
workers = 2 # Limited by CPU cores (2)
threads = 1
# Of course much more detail here that I can load test...but will leave it there to keep the question simple

# kube
Pods: 5-7 (horizontal autoscaling)
```

If we assume 150ms average response time, I'd roughly calculate a total capacity of 93requests/second - somewhat short of our peak. In our logs we often get `uWSGI listen queue of socket ... full` logs, which makes sense.

My question is...what are our options here to handle this spike? Limitations:

- It seems the 128 listen queue is determined by the kernal, and the kube docs suggest it's [unsafe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#podsecuritypolicy) to increase this.
- Our Kube nodes have 2 cores. The general advice seems to be to set your number of workers to 2 * cores (possibly + 1), so we're pretty much at our limit here. Increasing to 3 doesn't seem to have much impact.
- Multiple threads in Django can apparently cause weird bugs

Is our only option to keep scaling this horizontally at the kubernetes level? Aside from making our queries/caching as efficient as possible of course.

Comment: Sounds like you're considering the hardware approach to scaling, but what about the side? Are you caching expensive queries? Adding database indexes where needed? Also making third party requests within the context of an existing request is usually going to be a huge bottleneck and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Good point...meant to mention improving the efficiency of the queries themselves and making good use of caching.

Comment: I'd recommend starting out by analyzing what database queries you're making in a given request and understanding if there's any quick-wins in optimizing those. From there, I'd definitely address the constraint of communicating with third parties. That information could be pulled on a schedule or cached heavily but should ideally never be fetched with each request, especially at the load you're describing above.

Comment: All good advice. The response time for successful requests doesn't actually vary too much under peak load, which makes me think the bottleneck is further up. Think it's mainly a case of getting more requests through.
Of course bringing the average response time down would help with this.